# I installed a new App to Production, and it isn't in the sandbox. How do I update the sandbox with it without overwriting my current sandbox?

Tags: sandbox

I have a lot in my sandbox that is not ready to be pushed to production. I need to have access to a new Calendar App that is in production in the sandbox, but I'm worried that updating it or "Refreshing" as it's called will overwrite my current sandbox. Suggestions? Pushing current box to production is not an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install the app in Sandbox if you don't want to refresh the sandbox.

Comment: When I find the App online and I click their link to get it by signing into SF, it brings me to the regular login, so I don't know how to install it to the sandbox. Is there a way to do this within the SB instead of using the external link?

Comment: Sorry -- logged in anyway and I now have the option. Thank you!

Comment: @NatalieSpatharakis Please mark it as answer if it solves your question